# iPhone game center nickname

Tags: iphone, game-center

I used my nickname on iPhone 5's Game Center before I changed my Apple ID to [appleid]@cloud.com. After changing my Apple ID to an @icloud.com account, I then deleted my old Apple ID from my iPhone. Now both my nickname and scores disappeared.

Is there any way to get my nickname and scores back?

Comment: So you changed Apple IDs entirely? Or just the [email associated with the Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE40)?

Answer (score 1):

You can log into your old account again directly in the GameCenter app:

- start GameCenter
- go to your profile and scroll down
- tap on your account name (at the bottom) to log out
- log in with the old account